# Value of type '[vector_float3]' (aka 'Array<float3>') has no member 'advanced'

Tags: swift4, arkit

In arkit example code by apple i'm getting this error Value of type '[vector_float3]' (aka 'Array') has no member 'advanced'
it was working fine with XCode 9 beta version or GM version

I'm using this code

```
func hitTestWithFeatures(_ point: CGPoint, coneOpeningAngleInDegrees: Float,
                             minDistance: Float = 0,
                             maxDistance: Float = Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude,
                             maxResults: Int = 1) -> [FeatureHitTestResult] {

        var results = [FeatureHitTestResult]()

        guard let features = self.session.currentFrame?.rawFeaturePoints else {
            return results
        }

        guard let ray = hitTestRayFromScreenPos(point) else {
            return results
        }

        let maxAngleInDeg = min(coneOpeningAngleInDegrees, 360) / 2
        let maxAngle = ((maxAngleInDeg / 180) * Float.pi)

        let points = features.points

        for i in 0...features.__count {

            let feature = points.advanced(by: Int(i))
            let featurePos = SCNVector3(feature.pointee)

            let originToFeature = featurePos - ray.origin

            let crossProduct = originToFeature.cross(ray.direction)
            let featureDistanceFromResult = crossProduct.length()

            let hitTestResult = ray.origin + (ray.direction * ray.direction.dot(originToFeature))
            let hitTestResultDistance = (hitTestResult - ray.origin).length()


            // All tests passed: Add the hit against this feature to the results.
            results.append(FeatureHitTestResult(position: hitTestResult,
                                                distanceToRayOrigin: hitTestResultDistance,
                                                featureHit: featurePos,
                                                featureDistanceToHitResult: featureDistanceFromResult))
        }

        // Sort the results by feature distance to the ray.
        results = results.sorted(by: { (first, second) -> Bool in
            return first.distanceToRayOrigin < second.distanceToRayOrigin
        })

        return cappedResults
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was having the same issue, happily solved. Apple has already updated this example here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AudioInARKit/Listings/Audio_in_ARKit_ARSCNView_HitTests_swift.html

Just small change and you are ok:

```
let points = features.__points
```

instead of:

```
let points = features.points
```

Hope this helps